# Config file not found using heroku and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: heroku, cloud

I've created a spring boot application that is deployed on heroku.
Everything works fine.. Now, I am trying to use the Text to Speech api from google cloud.  This works fine locally but when I want to use it on `heroku` i get the warning.

> Error reading credential file from environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'config/keyFile.json': File does
>   not exist.

I've set in heroku the following :

```
 heroku config:set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=‘config/keyFile.json’
```

No matter where i put the file.. I cannot get it to work.
Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by setting a heroku config variable (say GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) with the contents of the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file and calling the `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` where the client needs to be instantiated.

In any case, it is not a best practice to save key files to a remote server (such as heroku), and is safer to call the key using an environment variable.

```
// Where you need to instantiate the google project client,
var keyValue = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);
// set the 'credentials' parameter with keyValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with vercel where it was unable to find the serviceaccount.json. I finally got it to work by passing the credenitals to directly to the TextToSpeechClient constructor as an object. Just remember to use environment variables for the sensitive properties.

```
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient({
    credentials: {
      type: "service_account",
      project_id: "",
      private_key_id: "",
      private_key:"",
      client_email: "",
      client_id: "",
      auth_uri: "",
      token_uri: "",
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "",
      client_x509_cert_url:"",
    },
  });
```

You can see the Google documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/text-to-speech/latest/text-to-speech/v1.texttospeechclient

The documentation is not very clear as to how the ClientOptions object should look like. I just took a guess at the credentials {credentials:{}} part and it worked.

Hope this helps who what to deploy to the cloud and are struggling with getting the right path to the serviceaccount.json